# SQL Server Select on Different column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I want to select a value based on different column in SQL Server,

say

```
Result = Isnull(A.OUT1,'')<>'' then select A.OUT1
         Isnull(A.OUT2,'')<>'' then select A.OUT2
         Isnull(A.OUT3,'')<>'' then select A.OUT3
```

How to form query to get the Result?

Comment: I do not understand the question. What do you get, what is wrong with it, and what do you want to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN isnull(a.out1,'')  '' THEN a.out1
         WHEN isnull(a.out2,'')  '' THEN a.out2
         WHEN isnull(a.out3,'')  '' THEN a.out3
         ELSE ''
       END AS out_column
FROM the_table a
```